# video player for angular with jwt support

Tags: angular, jwt, video-player

I'm trying to stream video in chunks from Spring boot microservice to Angular frontend app. Video source is secured with JWT, so when sending request for video there is need to pass JWT token to this request.

Example get request for video:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/stream-service/video/${this.videoPath} 
with headers: Authorization: Bearer xxxx
```

here is example how I'm trying to achieve this

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { SomeResponse } from '../../models';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-info-dialog',
  templateUrl: './some-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-dialog.component.css']
})
export class SomeDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoPlayer: ElementRef;
  readonly mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
  readonly some: SomeResponse;
  readonly someVideoUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SomeDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
    this.some = data.some;
    this.someVideoUrl = `http://localhost:8080/api/stream-service/video/${this.some.videoPath}`;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (
      'MediaSource' in window &&
      MediaSource.isTypeSupported(this.mimeCodec)
    ) {
      const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
      (this.videoPlayer.nativeElement as HTMLVideoElement).src = URL.createObjectURL(
        mediaSource
      );
      mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () =>
        this.sourceOpen(mediaSource)
      );
    } else {
      console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', this.mimeCodec);
    }
  }

  private sourceOpen(mediaSource): Subscription {
    const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(this.mimeCodec);
    return this.http
      .get(this.someVideoUrl, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .subscribe(blob => {
        sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
          mediaSource.endOfStream();
          this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.play();
        });
        blob.arrayBuffer().then(x => sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(x));
      });
  }

}
```

Every request through httpClient is intercepted and JWT token is added before it reach the video resource server.

```html
<video style="width: 100%" controls #videoPlayer>
  Browser not supported
</video>
<h2> {{ some.name }}</h2>
<h3>Opis</h3>
<p> {{ some.description }}</p>
<p> {{ some.test1 }}</p>
<p> {{ some.test2 }}</p>
```

Following solution is working when I'm using endpoint that is not secured with JWT. Does somebody know how to get video from streaming API that is secured with JWT token?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get video from endpoint that is secured with JWT token. Out of the box video player don't give you this feature and I can't find they way to achieve it.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent people from downloading your video even though they have the JWT ?

Comment: No, I don't. If I use some plugin for chrome to append to request headers and I use url to get video and I pass JWT token in authorization headers I'm able to get the video in the browser. The secured endpoint works also in postman. The problem I have that video player in html don't support out of the box adding JWT token to url request. I was trying to get the stream of video and pass this stream to video player. I really can't find way to pass this stream to the player.